# How to prevent Word from opening multiple docs during recursion?

Tags: excel, recursion, vbscript, ms-word

I am trying to search sub-folders for a filename, open the Excel file, and copy/paste to Word. The way my code is right now it opens a new Word doc every time. How can I paste one item from each Excel file into the same Word doc?

```
Sub Word(f)
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add("C:\Users\ntunstall\Desktop\test\Doc1.docx")
    objWord.Visible = True
    objDoc.PageSetup.Orientation = 1
    objDoc.Paragraphs.Alignment = 1

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objWkb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(f)
    objExcel.Visible = False

    objWkb.Sheets("PresRate").ChartObjects("Chart 1").CopyPicture
    objWord.Selection.Paste
    objWord.Selection.MoveRight
    objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph

    objWkb.Save
    objWkb.Close
End Sub

Dim path: path = "C:\Users\ntunstall\Desktop\test"
Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Call TraverseFolders(fso.GetFolder(path))

Sub TraverseFolders(fldr)
  Dim f, sf
  For Each f In fldr.Files
    If InStr(f.Name, "OPS") > 0 Then
        If InStr(f.Name, "xlsm") > 0 Then
            Call Word(f)
        End If
    End If
  Next

  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    Call TraverseFolders(sf)
  Next
End Sub

wScript.Quit
objWord.Quit
objExcel.Quit

Set objDoc = Nothing
Set objWkb = Nothing
```

I have tried moving parts of `Sub Word(f)` in/out of the sub, and in/out of `Sub TraverseFolders(fldr)`. The objects either become out of scope or the program still opens multiple word docs.

Comment: `GetObject(Fname)` to open or connect to an open file. `GetObject(,"Word.Application")` to connect to an already running Word (and error if there isn't one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the the code that starts Word and creates a new document from your procedure `Word` to the global scope. I would also move creation of the Excel object to the global scope, because you need only one instance.

Change this:

```
Sub Word(f)
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add("C:\Users\ntunstall\Desktop\test\Doc1.docx")
    objWord.Visible = True
    objDoc.PageSetup.Orientation = 1
    objDoc.Paragraphs.Alignment = 1

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objWkb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(f)
    objExcel.Visible = False

    objWkb.Sheets("PresRate").ChartObjects("Chart 1").CopyPicture
    objWord.Selection.Paste
    objWord.Selection.MoveRight
    objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph

    objWkb.Save
    objWkb.Close
End Sub

Dim path: path = "C:\Users\ntunstall\Desktop\test"
Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Call TraverseFolders(fso.GetFolder(path))
```

to this:

```
Sub Word(f)
    Set objWkb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(f)

    objWkb.Sheets("PresRate").ChartObjects("Chart 1").CopyPicture
    objWord.Selection.Paste
    objWord.Selection.MoveRight
    objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph

    objWkb.Save
    objWkb.Close
End Sub

Dim path: path = "C:\Users\ntunstall\Desktop\test"
Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add("C:\Users\ntunstall\Desktop\test\Doc1.docx")
objWord.Visible = True
objDoc.PageSetup.Orientation = 1
objDoc.Paragraphs.Alignment = 1

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False

Call TraverseFolders(fso.GetFolder(path))
```

Also change this:

```
WScript.Quit
objWord.Quit
objExcel.Quit

Set objDoc = Nothing
Set objWkb = Nothing
```

to this:

```
objExcel.Quit
```

because calling `WScript.Quit` first leaves Word *and* Excel instances running when you apparently just want to keep the Word instance, and variables are cleared automatically upon termination of the script.

Comment: Thank you! Edited OP with solution.

Comment: @Nathan Please don't do that. Answers should not be included in questions.